# Creating a vector with the age-specific background mortality rates from CSV file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to vreate a vector (v_mort) with the age-specific background mortality but I get an error message:

> Error in `select()`: ! Can't subset columns that don't exist. ✖ Column
> `Total` doesn't exist.

My csv data (mortality.csv)looks like this:

```
Year;Age;Female;Male;Total
2021;0;0,00165;0,00203;0,002069453
2021;1;0,0002;0,0002;0,000193653
```

[As it appears in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbU2r.png)

etc..

I use this formula:

```
 Mortality_2022 <- read.csv("C:\\mortality.csv")

    v_mort <- Mortality_2022 %>% 
  # filter(Age >= age & Age <= n_age_max) %>%
  select (total) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some syntax problem? (for instance upper case, lower case difference). Check your variable name with `View(Mortality_2022)`. It may be the issue

Comment: Hi !

I tried viewing the data and it looks ok I think. Edited the post and added a link to show you how it appears in R.

Comment: Tried capital T and didnt work. 
Still: Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `.Total` doesn't exist.

Comment: Your data is not a CSV file but a ; separated file, thus you are probably having difficulty getting the data in.  Try adding the `sep = ";"` option to the `read.csv()` function.

Comment: Added `sep = ";"` but I still get the same error. My code is now:  

`Mortality_2022 <- read.csv("C:\\mortality.csv", sep = ";")

    v_mort <- Mortality_2022 %>% 
  # filter(Age >= age & Age <= n_age_max) %>%
  select (Total) %>%
  as.matrix()`

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Got it working with this code

`Mortality_2022 <- read.csv("C:\\mortality.csv")
v_mort <- Mortality_2022 %>% 
                   select(Total) %>%
                   as.matrix()
names(v_mort) <- Mortality_2022$Age`